# One-minute periodic service

Tags: android, android-service

What's the correct way to perform a periodic task?
My implementation does not seem to work properly: when the screen is on and I am using the phone the service method is ran perfectly in time. However when the phone is locked the service is ran at very large and random intervals (e.g: 10:30 10:32 10:45 10:46 10:49 11:00...)
Here is the code:

MAIN SERVICE CLASS:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
    showNotification();
    mHandler.postDelayed(periodicTask, ONE_MINUTE); 
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private static final int ONE_MINUTE = 60000;

private Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try{
            wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");    
            wakelock.acquire();
            Log.v("PeriodicTimerService","Awake");
            getValues();
            writeDB();
            writeLog();
            mHandler.postDelayed(periodicTask, ONE_MINUTE);
        }
        finally{
            wakelock.release();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936334/1321873

Comment: Yeah, I already looked at alarm manager but it didn't seem to me the best option :" Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler."
also my period is very short (one minute), so I think that the alarm manager is not the best choice in this case

Comment: CHECK THIS ONE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117982/how-to-loop-a-service

Comment: As I stated in the question, it doesn't work properly when the phone is sleeping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the periodic task to run exactly every minute even while the phone is sleeping then you have no choice: You must use the AlarmManager.

Comment: ok thank for the clear answer :)
is it very battery draining?

Comment: I'm sure the battery consumption will vary from device to device. However, I don't think waking up the phone once a minute is going to drain the battery. The real question is: what are you doing when you wake the phone up? Things that really deplete the battery are: GPS fix, establish Internet connection, turn on screen. Just try not to do those things every minute, or give the user the option to disable your application from waking up every minute.

Comment: no, my application has to retrieve some data from the sensor like the accelermoeter and stuff like that

Comment: Then it shouldn't be too draining. Of course, you should test this on a real device just to see. If my answer has been helpful I would appreciate it if you would accept it (green checkmark). Thanks!