# Collect device data on android regularly

Tags: android

I managed to create an application that collects basic info from the device like android version,CPU,total RAM,free RAM,etc. Some of the data i need to collect is dynamic so i want my application to collect that data every minute.I also want my application to do so in the background. Here is how my code is setup:

```
public class Sniffer extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sniffer);
        model_device=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.model1);
        versiune_android=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.versiune1);
        total_RAM=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_RAM1);
        free_RAM=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.free_RAM1);
        total_disk=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_disk1);
        free_disk=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.free_disk1);
        CPU=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.CPU1);
        nivel_baterie=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.baterie1);

        //get the requested data and set the corresponding text
        getDeviceData();
}
```

Inside getDeviceData i read the /proc files and whatnot to obtain everything. Can i create a service that can run in the background and every x minutes update the data by calling getDeviceData again ? Let's take this scenario : start my app,check the data, leave app on, go check my email, listen to a song on youtube then i come back to my app (without closing it)and the collected data should have changed. How would i go about doing so using a service, i think this is the best solution. I need just a bump in the right direction, maybe a skeleton code on where my stuff should go. Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you at least looked at the Android documentation, e.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?

Comment: Yes i have read the documentation and several other tutorials but i'm parsing too much information at once and it's easy to get confused(i am a beginner in android). What i understand is I need to create a service class which is started by an intent inside the activity class and every x minutes it should send the requested data to the activity ? Something like timer.scheduleAtFixedRate{ public void run(){do work here; send data(how?) } }

Comment: What you are trying to do has been done many times before. Try googling for what you need. When I googled "android run task periodically inside a service" I got several hits, including this one that seems to be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482583/one-minute-periodic-service

Comment: Thanks, will check it out in the morning and work something off it.